# Why is my result of type List<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Two queries that should result in a list of account numbers (strings).  However the second query actually returns a `List<IEnumerable<string>>`, where I would like it to return a `List<string>`.  What am I doing wrong?

```
//the type here resolves to List<string>
var acts = (from a in base.context.Accounts
            select a.AccountNumber).ToList();

//the type here resolves to List<IEnumerable<string>>
var uAccounts = (from u in base.context.Users
                 select u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)).ToList();
```

Comment: You have an inner LINQ query in your `select` clause that returns an `IEnumerable<string>`, so in your outer query you're collating all the `IEnumerable<string>`s to an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` before turning it into a list.

Comment: how would I rewrite that query to achieve my desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
var uAccounts = (from u in base.context.Users
             select u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)).ToList();
```

to

```
var uAccounts = base.context.Users.SelectMany(u => 
                u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)).ToList();
```

And to actually answer your question, the difference between the two lines of your code is that the first one goes through every single account and selects just the account number.  The second statement selects an embedded Linq query of `IEnumerable<string>`.  So you are converting to a `List<T>` of these `IEnumerable<string>`

That actually shows the benefit of the [SelectMany extention method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) (I'm not actually sure about how to use that in a query statement).  The SelectMany method instead flattens the `IEnumerable<T>` you would normally receive to a single enumeration of the `T` element.  So when `ToList()` is called, it will return you a `List<string>` instead of the enumerable.

Answer (score 3):

Your `select` clause is returning / nests another `select` operation and hence you end up with nested enumerations.  To flatten the list you need to use `SelectMany` instead.

```
var acts = base.context.Accousts
  .SelectMany(a => x.AccountNumber)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

`u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)` by itself gives you an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Then wrapping that in `from u in base.context.Users select u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)` gives you an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.

Then calling `.ToList()` on that gives `List<IEnumerable<string>>`.

Answer (score 2):

While you could use `SelectMany`, it is more straightforward to nest your from clauses:

```
var uAccounts = (from u in base.context.Users
                  from a in u.Accounts
                    select a.AccountNumber).ToList();
```

When and if you use products like NHibernate, you will want to know this idiom, as it is a very straightforward way to do table joins in the resulting SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

In the second query, you are doing a second select that's creating your inner list

This returns an `IEnumerable<string>`

```
 u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)
```

and then your are wrapping it in another select that creates the outer list

Answer (score 1):

I think I need to use `u.Accounts.SelectMany(...)` to get the desired result.

Comment: Close, but it's the outer select that needs to be `SelectMany`

Answer (score 1):

`u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)`

is a list of Account number

so

```
(from u in base.context.Users
     select u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber))
```

is an IEnumerable of lists of account numbers

adding .ToList()

Makes it a List of lists of account numbers

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, the `ToList()` only applies to the outer list, which itself consists of lists.

Answer (score 0):

`u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)`  returns `IEnumerable<string>`

`select u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)`   returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`

`select u.Accounts.Select(s => s.AccountNumber)).ToList();`   just turns the outer IEnumerable into IList